# Checking field is blank or not to upload image file

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I can't validate upload field. the field name is an array. how to validate it using jquery?
here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    var validator = $("#signupform").submit(function() {
            // update underlying textarea before submit validation
        }).validate({
        rules: {
            name: "required",

            photo_path: { required: true }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(label, element) {

                    label.insertAfter(element);

            },
        messages: {
            name: "Please enter your name",

            photo_path: "Upload your Image"
        }
    });

});
</script>




<?php
 $count=1;
 for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
 {
?>
             <input type="hidden" name="galleryImage[]" id="galleryImage[]" value="<?=$i?>"/>   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" bordercolor="1" class="signup">Upload Image <?=$count?>:</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" bordercolor="1"><input type="file" name="photo_path[]" id="photo_path"  class="inputcolor_text" />
      <br />            
<?php
$count++;
}
?>
```

Comment: why is the id in brackets? especially when u have `$i` it's only the name that posted as an array

Comment: I uploaded 4 images together thats why it is an array. and $i for the "for loop".

Comment: I understand but, [not that i know of] the ID does not support `[]` to be unique as you are thinking, the name="bla[]" means that data will be posted as an array and php understands that well, but browsers do not support IDs in that way.

Comment: @Val, yes that is my problem. thats why my upload field is not validate. and I don't know how to solve this problem. is any other way?? if I not mention **photo_path[]** as an array then I can't upload all 4 images together.

Comment: and omg, you still are using tables? it's not 1990s catch up :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go...

```
var validator = $("#signupform").submit(function(e) {
  if(!$('.inputcolor_text').val()){
     e.preventDefault();
     // $('#error').html('Cannot be empty.');
     return false;
    }
}).validate.....
```